# How to override exit() call in Perl eval block

Tags: perl, eval

I need to `eval` some code in Perl that might some times contain an `exit()` call in it. A very simplified example of this would be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;


eval "some_function()";
die $@ if $@;

print "Still alive!\n";


sub some_function {
    print "Hello from some_function\n";
    exit;
}
```

I never get to "Still alive!" because of the `exit()` call.

I tried setting some keys in `%SIG` (QUIT, STOP, TERM, BREAK, etc) but that didn't work. I also attempted to redefine `CORE::exit` with no success.

**How can I prevent an `exit()` call from being effective when being `eval`ed?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can override `exit`, but you must do so at compile-time. So use a flag to signal whether the override is active or not.

```perl
our $override_exit = 0;
BEGIN { 
   *CORE::GLOBAL::exit = sub(;$) {
      CORE::exit( $_[0] // 0 ) if !$override_exit;

      die "EXIT_OVERRIDE\n";
   };
}

eval {
   local $override_exit = 1;
   some_function();
};

if ( !$@ ) {
   say "Normal return";
} elsif ( $@ eq "EXIT_OVERRIDE\n" ) {
   say "Exit called";
} else {
   print "Exception: $@";
}
```

But that creates an exception that might be caught unintentionally. So let's use `last` instead.

```perl
our $override_exit = 0;
BEGIN { 
   *CORE::GLOBAL::exit = sub(;$) {
      CORE::exit( $_[0] // 0 ) if !$override_exit;

      no warnings qw( exiting );
      last EXIT_OVERRIDE;
   };
}

my $exit_called = 1;
EXIT_OVERRIDE: {
   local $override_exit = 1;
   eval { some_function() };
   $exit_called = 0;
}

if ( $exit_called ) {
   say "Exit called";
} elsif ( $@ ) {
   print "Exception: $@";
} else {
   say "Normal return";
}
```

---

Note that `eval BLOCK` is used to catch exceptions. `eval EXPR` is used to compile code.

Comment: Very nice, thanks again. :-) So, if the evaled code explicitly calls `CORE::exit`, I guess I won't be able to stop that. Right?

Comment: You'd have to install an opcode checker to change the ppaddr of `exit` opcodes, I think.

Comment: Great solution, but seems a bit too long to be called a simple solution.

Answer (score 7):

`exit` isn't meant to be trapped, so `eval` isn't the solution here. You could put the remaining code you need to run in an `END` block:

```
some_function();
END { print "Still alive! For now...\n"; }

sub some_function {
    print "Hello from some_function\n";
    exit;
}
```

But if you absolutely, positively need to prevent `exit` from killing the script, you'll have to redefine `exit()` at compile time:

```
BEGIN { *CORE::GLOBAL::exit = sub (;$) { } } # Make exit() do nothing
some_function();
print "Still alive!\n"; # Gets printed

*CORE::GLOBAL::exit = *CORE::exit; # Restore exit()
exit;
print "I'm dead here.\n"; # Doesn't get printed

sub some_function { exit }
```

The Test::Trap module from the CPAN can be used to encapsulate this bit of ugliness for you, if you're interested in a more robust solution. Personally I would locally patch the `exit`ing `some_function()` to use `croak` instead, and maybe file a bug report with the patch if it's a module.

If you're just `eval`ing user input and you don't want them to be able to call `exit`, verify that the string contains no calls to `exit` or to a subroutine that would indirectly exit, then `eval` it. Personally I'd be more afraid of `unlink` and `fork` than `exit` if the user is inputting arbitrary code to be evaluated.

Comment: Any way to treat exit like die? (So capture and keep going as normal with the rest of the program)