# Catch Errors Separately from Calls to Die in Perl

Tags: perl, error-handling

I have code that is occasionally running into a fatal error after running for several hours and I'm not sure why. I'm trying to use a custom `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler to catch these unexpected terminations, but doing so interferes with my modification of `CORE::GLOBAL::die` (derived from [@ikegami's helpful modification of `CORE::GLOBAL::exit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67051296/656780) that he suggested to me on another question). `$SIG{__DIE__}` seems to take precedence over `CORE::GLOBAL::die`, but `CORE::GLOBAL::die` only fires when `die` is explicitly called, not when there is an error.

What I would like is to have my custom handler *only* fire on actual errors whereas my custom `CORE::GLOBAL::die` can be allowed to handle direct calls to `die`.

Here's my code:

```
local $SIG{__DIE__} = \&customErrorHandler;

BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::die = sub(;$) {
        &SAFARI::Core::safariErrorLogWriter('Die called.') unless $main::handleDeathLog;

        last EXIT_OVERRIDE if $main::override_exit;
        say STDERR 'Actually going to die now.';
        CORE::die($_[0] // 0);
    };  
}
```

Given this code, `&customErrorHandler` is called instead of CORE::GLOBAL::die even when I directly call `die`. I considered making the **DIE** handler call `CORE::GLOBAL::die`, but that has two issues:

1. The call to the label `last EXIT_OVERRIDE` works fine when the routine is called with `die`, but not if there is an error, so my error handler causes an error itself then.
2. To deal with that, I thought about wrapping the call to `CORE::GLOBAL::die` to disable that label call in cases of an actual error:

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub { $main::override_exit = 0; die; };
```

However, `SAFARI::Core::safariErrorLogWriter` uses `caller()` to get details to log. If it is called sometimes only one level away from the issue (when `die` is called directly) and sometimes *two* levels away (when the handler uses the anonymous wrapper sub to call `die`), sometimes `caller` will need to be `caller(1)` and sometimes `caller(2)`.

Comment: I gota little  lost along the way ... so do you want  custom code to run for (certain kinds of?) errors (`customErrorHandler` in `$SIG{__DIE__}`) but other custom code to run when `die` is called explicitly (given in `CORE::GLOBAL::die`) ...?

Comment: I don't see that the `SIG{__DIE__}` hook overrides `CORE::GLOBAL::die` for direct call to `die` ...? `perl -wE'BEGIN { *CORE::GLOBAL::die = sub(;$) { say "global (@_)" } }; $SIG{__DIE__} = sub { say "hook (@_)" }; die "bye"; say "done"'`

Comment: @zdim Correct, I want to handle die one way, but handle things that unintentionally cause the script to die another way. That's interesting regarding your test code -- I need to investigate further and figure out why it doesn't play out the same way with mine. Hmm...

Comment: There is a `CORE::die` in the `CORE::GLOBAL::die` sub  so the `$SIG{__DIE__}` hook (handler) probably fires for _that_ (along with more happening), or for some other code in there

Comment: @zdim I think that makes perfect sense. I've been trying to figure out why the issue occurs on the command line but not in CGI. But when it is running as a CGI script, it avoids that `CORE::die`. Thank you! I'm trying to throw things at it to see if I'm missing something, but I think that's the ticket.

Comment: Alright, great if that clears it up.  Drop a note here once you resolve it...